# Is there a way to publish a lightroom web gallery via ssh/scp?

Tags: lightroom

I see there is a way to publish via FTP but I can't find any plugins that allow to scp.

I did a plugin for publishing collections via ssh/scp on github written by [knutsiem](https://github.com/knutsiem/ssh-lightroom-plugin) but it doesn't work with web galleries.

Comment: How about `sshfs`?

Comment: Ftp->scp bridge would help?

Answer (score 1):

Lightroom supports publishing to sftp. If your server supports ssh then sftp should be a option you can enable. It turns out I needed to edit the sshd_config to support it and it worked.